# Include additional R pkg in custom JupyterHub user notebook image?

Tags: r, docker, cran, jupyterhub

I customize the user notebook environment [like so](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing/user-environment.html#customize-an-existing-docker-image) (installing custom python packages)

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:177037d09156
# Get the latest image tag at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/minimal-notebook/tags/
# Inspect the Dockerfile at:
# https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook/Dockerfile

# install additional package...
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir astropy
```

How can I install custom R packages? Specifically, I am looking to install:

- reticulate
- mvtnorm
- gdata
- matrixcalc
- gtools
- mpoly
- moments

These are available in CRAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install it (with using `jupyter/minimal-notebook` as the base image instead of `jupyter/r-notebook`), like so:

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:177037d09156
# Get the latest image tag at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/minimal-notebook/tags/
# Inspect the Dockerfile at:
# https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/minimal-notebook/Dockerfile

RUN R -e 'install.packages("gtools", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("gdata", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("reticulate", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
RUN R -e 'install.packages("matrixcalc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use R packages and jupyter notebook, I would suggest using `jupyter/r-notebook` as a base image. To install R packages afterwards, install them with `conda`.

```
FROM jupyter/r-notebook
RUN conda install --yes \
        r-reticulate r-mvtnorm r-gdata r-matrixcalc \
        r-gtools r-mpoly r-moments \
    && conda clean --all --yes
```

Comment: I also need to install additional python packages, to be used in python notebooks. How can I do both? (install additional R and additional python packages)

Comment: Add the python packages to that `conda install` command. If those packages are not packaged by `conda`, then you can install them with `pip`, but `conda` is preferred.

Comment: Hi jackub, is it necessary to inherit `FROM jupyter/r-notebook` ? Our current setup has multiple layers of images, that inherit `FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook:177037d09156` as a root image -- so switching to `FROM jupyter/r-notebook` as a new base image would be a lot of effort. Is it possible to install additional R packages on top of `jupyter/minimal-notebook:177037d09156`

Comment: I guess it is not necessary, as you wrote in your answer. Good luck!

Comment: I actually tried your example (using conda) on the minimal-notebook base image, and the R kernel was broken (no code would run) hence me searching for an alternative (running R install.packages directly). I think your answer is definitely useful though for anyone willing to use `jupyter/r-notebook` - thanks